# How to load list to DataFrame and iterate over iterrows?

Tags: python

I have the following code I wrote:

```
        df = pandas.DataFrame(temp_data_list)
        return [X(first, rest.tolist()) for first, rest in df.iterrows()]
```

The `temp_data_list` is a list of lists for example `[['a',1,2,3],['b',3,2,1]]`. I want to convert it to DataFrame and iterate over `iterrows` and for each element, insert the `'a'` to be `first` and the rest should be `[1,2,3]`. For some reason it inserts `'a'` to the rest. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

iterrows yields (index, values)

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1,2,3],['b',3,2,1]])
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    first, *rest = row
    print(first, rest)
```

If, for some odd reason, you want it in one line...

```py
ret = [(first, rest) for idx, (first, *rest) in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: Well you did not say you wanted it in one line. You can turn my answer into a list comprehension. But what's this obsession with cramming everything in one line? Do you think it'll make your code look more clever?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misinterpreting, but it sounds like this is what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
temp_data_list = [['a',1,2,3],['b',3,2,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(temp_data_list)
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([df.iloc[i,0], list(df.iloc[i, 1:])]) for i in range(len(df))])
```

```
In [51]: df
   0          1
0  a  [1, 2, 3]
1  b  [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close with what you tried.  The big thing is that `iterrows()` returns two things, an index value and the row data.  So you have to accept that index (`idx` below).  The other thing is that what you were doing with the `rest` part of the problem wasn't quite right.  Here's a similar line that does what you want:

```
r = [X(first, rest) for idx, (first, *rest) in df.iterrows()]
```

and here's a full working example, including a definition for 'X':

```
import pandas as pd

class X:
    def __init__(self, first, rest):
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"X('{self.first}', {self.rest})"

df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1,2,3],['b',3,2,1]])

r = [X(first, rest) for idx, (first, *rest) in df.iterrows()]

print(r)
```

Result:

```
[X('a', [1, 2, 3]), X('b', [3, 2, 1])]
```